# highcharts - How do I show/hide secondary y axis based on optional parameter

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to functionalize my highchart code and I am struggling to understand how can I make a secondary y Axis drawn based on a conditional if statement such as the code below:

```
 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis shown for all charts
              min: 0,
              labels: {
                  format: '{value} pcks ',
                  style: {
                      color: '#4572A7'
                  }
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Volume',
                  style: {
                      color: '#4572A7'
                  }
              }
          }, { // Secondary yAxis make this optional based on AxisNum accepted values:1/2 
              formatter: function(){ 
                  if(AxisNum === 2])
                  {
                      gridLineWidth: 0, min:0, title: { text: 'Cycle Time', style: { color: '#C88622' } }, labels: {format: '{value} days',style: {color: '#C88622'}},opposite: true;
                  }
              } 

          }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condition which check your AxisNum, then prepare object correct yAxis and in options you will use

```
yAxis: yAxisCustomised
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92u9M/1/